# How to ensure succesfull app deployment?

Tags: devops

In DEVOPs how to ensure that web application is perfectly deployed (*not partial or failed*) and rollback in case of any failure.

**What should be best practice in steps for same?**, *Like it could be push release as zip, uncompress zip, bla bla bla ...*.

Comment: Your question is a little vague, but I would look at some Tests and a Continuous Integration Server (like Jenkins). If all your tests pass, then it can deploy the system which is driven mainly by your repository server.

Comment: It's not vague, lets say I've 20 files to be deployed and only part say 15 gets deployed due to some reason, there will be chaos. This is **transactional deployment, status detection and rollback** for entire website. I hope, this comment makes it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ... now you are providing more information and my previous comment is invalid.

My suggestion is write a deployment system that takes the files one by and deploys them. Add an input of the number of files that need to be deployed as well as a checksum of the expanded files and a checksum of the compressed files and then use all these values in your deployment system to ensure the deployments work correctly.

I did something similar for a self update system that uses Linux and Java here ... basically I pass it some checksums and when it had deployed the file it compares the checksums and if correct it moves on to the next step.

I personally am not aware of any off the shelf product that will do this for you.

Good luck.

Comment: I agree, but this fails if **part files are successfully deployed**, am too seeking any *off the shelf product or technique for same*. By the way thanks, I guess presently checksum is the only way

Comment: But your checksum would be on the extracted files ... so you would run a checksum before zipping and then after zipping ... if any file is corrupt or missing your checksum would fail.